# what's the difference between one to one call and group call [agora.io]

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I can't figure out the difference between one-to-one video call and a video group call, I want to set up a video group call using agora SDK but I don't know how ! when I go through the documentation I find a demo and tutorial for one-to-one video call, is it the same as group call or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agora video calls are, by default, group calls. You don't have to configure anything special. You just need to make sure that you have a scalable UI.

The one-to-one video calling examples have user interfaces that can not scale beyond two users, whereas the group video calling examples have user interfaces that can scale.